# Maximum number of saved embedded form in Symfony 1.4

Tags: forms, internationalization, doctrine, symfony-1.4, limit

I can't save more then 67 widgets on my one-to-many form with Symfony 1.4
I embedded an Element table which embeds the i18n translation table.
It saves everything correctly but I cannot save more then 67 records.

The structure is:
MAIN > ELEMENT > i18n
For 1 MAIN I got several elements which are translated.
Do you if there's a limit on the number of updates/insert?
Thank you

Comment: Check in `php.ini` `max_post_size`,  `max_input_vars` and `max_input_nesting_level`. Maybe problem in on of those parameters.

Comment: It was like you said. The max_input_vars in php.ini was setted to 1000 and it was sending in POST more than 1000 variables. Thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the max_input_vars parameter in the php.ini configuration file.
It was 1000 but the POST was sending more than 1000 variables.